# Component re run multiple times on setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to set my state in component did Mount lifecycle method in order to check the data I am getting from local storage and taking decision either to direct the user to the login page or keep remain the user on the dashboard if my local storage data exists in my local storage.

Or is there any way I can prevent switching the page to login on refreshing the web page and remain on the same even after reloading the browser if I have my data in local storage.

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Row, Col, Input, Button, Alert, Container, Label } from "reactstrap";

// Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter, Link, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// availity-reactstrap-validation
import { AvForm, AvField } from "availity-reactstrap-validation";

// actions
import { checkLogin, apiError } from "../../store/actions";
import { loginAction } from "../../redux/actions/authActions";

// import images
import logodark from "../../assets/images/logo-dark.png";
import logolight from "../../assets/images/logo-light.png";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "246810",
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  async handleSubmit(event, values) {
    this.props.checkLogin(values, this.props.history);

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    localStorage.setItem("password", password);

    let action = await this.props.loginAction(values, () => {
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "/dashboard",
      });
    });
  }

  // username = localStorage.getItem("username");
  // password = localStorage.getItem("password");

  //   if (window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type).toSring() === 'back_forward') {
  //     window.location.reload()
  // }

  updateUser = (username, password) => {
    this.setState({ username: username, password: password });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.setState({
    //   // set username and password from local storage
    //   username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("username")),
    //   password: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("password")),
    // });

    const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    const password = localStorage.getItem("password");

    this.props.apiError("");
    document.body.classList.add("auth-body-bg");
    console.log("on page reload", window.performance.navigation);
    if (window.performance.navigation.type !== 0) {
      if (username && password) {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: "/dashboard",
        });
      } else {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: "/login",
        });
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("auth-body-bg");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <Container fluid className="p-0">
            <Row className="g-0">
              <Col lg={4}>
                <div className="authentication-page-content p-4 d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
                  <div className="w-100">
                    <Row className="justify-content-center">
                      <Col lg={9}>
                        <div>
                          <div className="text-center">
                            <div>
                              <Link to="/" class="">
                                <img
                                  src={logodark}
                                  alt=""
                                  height="20"
                                  class="auth-logo logo-dark mx-auto"
                                />
                                <img
                                  src={logolight}
                                  alt=""
                                  height="20"
                                  class="auth-logo logo-light mx-auto"
                                />
                              </Link>
                            </div>

                            <h4 className="font-size-18 mt-4">
                              Welcome Back !
                            </h4>
                            {/* <p className="text-muted">Sign in to continue to Nazox.</p> */}
                          </div>

                          {/* {this.props.loginError && this.props.loginError ? <Alert color="danger">{this.props.loginError}</Alert> : null} */}

                          <div className="p-2 mt-5">
                            <AvForm
                              className="form-horizontal"
                              onValidSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                            >
                              <div className="auth-form-group-custom mb-4">
                                <i className="ri-user-2-line auti-custom-input-icon"></i>
                                <Label htmlFor="username">Email</Label>
                                <AvField
                                  name="username"
                                  value={this.state.username}
                                  type="text"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  id="username"
                                  validate={{ email: true, required: true }}
                                  placeholder="Enter username"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="auth-form-group-custom mb-4">
                                <i className="ri-lock-2-line auti-custom-input-icon"></i>
                                <Label htmlFor="userpassword">Password</Label>
                                <AvField
                                  name="password"
                                  value={this.state.password}
                                  type="password"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  id="userpassword"
                                  placeholder="Enter password"
                                />
                              </div>

                              {/* <div className="form-check">
                                                                <Input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="customControlInline" />
                                                                <Label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="customControlInline">Remember me</Label>
                                                            </div> */}

                              <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                                <Button
                                  color="primary"
                                  className="w-md waves-effect waves-light"
                                  type="submit"
                                >
                                  Log In
                                </Button>
                              </div>

                              {/* <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                                                                <Link to="/forgot-password" className="text-muted"><i className="mdi mdi-lock me-1"></i> Forgot your password?</Link>
                                                            </div> */}
                            </AvForm>
                          </div>

                          <div className="mt-5 text-center">
                            <p>
                              Don't have an account ?{" "}
                              <Link
                                to="/register"
                                className="fw-medium text-primary"
                              >
                                {" "}
                                Register{" "}
                              </Link>{" "}
                            </p>
                            {/* <p>© 2021 Nazox. Crafted with <i className="mdi mdi-heart text-danger"></i> by Themesdesign</p> */}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col lg={8}>
                <div className="authentication-bg">
                  <div className="bg-overlay"></div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  const { loginError } = state.Login;
  return { loginError };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStatetoProps, { checkLogin, apiError, loginAction })(Login)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Setting state in `componentDidMount()` function is correct, just like what the error message said, are you calling `setState()` somewhere repeatedly?
Because when you call the `setState()` method the component rerenders, so if you call setState in a function that renders your component such as `render()` then it will call it infinitely

Comment: @kspc1000 No I am not using set state in my function

Comment: Do any of your imported functions cause any of your components to re-render?

Comment: no none of my imported functions does this

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to implement some **Error Boundaries** (if using React 16+);

If errors are not caught by any error boundary, this will result in unmounting of the whole component tree (https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html).

If the unmounting in turn changes something inside the store, this will cause re-rendering again in an infinite loop.

One error could occur (and probably not caught if you don't have Error Boundaries) beacuse you're using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("username"))` in `setState()`.

If the item inside localStorage is a normal string (as probably is), `JSON.parse(<string>)` will result in an error.

Comment: the error is mounting the state on render everytime